# What is $\mathfrak m_P\mathcal L_P$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I stumbled upon the term  $\mathfrak m_P\mathcal L_P$ in Hartshorne's book. The statement was (in short)

"s separates points, i.e. for distinct points $P$ and $Q$, $s\in \mathfrak m_P\mathcal L_P$ but $s\not \in\mathfrak m_Q\mathcal L_Q$ ?"

So what is the $\mathfrak m_P\mathcal L_P$  here? (I know that $\mathfrak m_P=\{s\mid s(P)=0\}$)

Kindly,

reinbot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\mathcal L$ is a line bundle, then in particular it is a sheaf of $\mathcal O_X$-modules, and localising, $\mathcal L_P$ is an $\mathcal O_{X,P}$-module. Thus it makes sense to multiply elements of $\mathcal L_P$ by elements of $\mathfrak m _{X,P}\subseteq\mathcal O_{X,P}.$ In particular, what is "meant" in this passage is that the section $s$ (of the line bundle $\mathcal L$) vanishes at $P$ but not at $Q.$

Comment: thx, that helped !